# Condense Pydantic Validators into Class Annotations

Tags: python, pydantic

Looking to create a datastructure in Python that condenses Pydantic's validators into oneline arguments:

ie. from this

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class MyClass(BaseModel):
    a: str
    b: str
    c: str
    
    @validator('b')
    def calculate_b(cls, v, values):
        return values['a'] + v
      
    @validator('c')
    def calculate_c(cls, v, values):
        return values['a'] + values['b'] + v
```

to (something like) this

```py
class MyClass:
    a: str
    b: str = calculate_b(...)
    c: str = calculate_c(...)
```

Comment: At the very least, you can call `validator` explicitly on a lambda expression instead of using decorator syntax on a `def` statement. `calcuate_b = validator('b')(lambda cls, v, values: values['a'] + v)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>My Pydantic version is: 2.5.0</sub>

---

**Note:** The `@validator` you used is deprecated in V2 and will be removed in V3. You should use `field_validator` instead if you want.

You can use `Annotated` + `AfterValidator`(actually the default mode for `field_validator` is `"after"`):

```py
from typing import Annotated

from pydantic import AfterValidator, BaseModel


class MyClass(BaseModel):
    a: str
    b: Annotated[str, AfterValidator(lambda v, values: values.data["a"] + v)]
    c: Annotated[str, AfterValidator(lambda v, values: values.data["a"] + values.data["b"] + v)]


obj = MyClass(a="a", b="b", c="c")
print(obj)
# a='a' b='ab' c='aabc'
```

If the annotation became long, you can make alias out of them outside the class. But I think it's ok.

The `values` are of type `ValidationInfo` and in order to access to the data you can use the `.data` attribute.

Comment: Thanks so much @S.B
How do I automatically call the `AfterValidator` without providing an input argument